# rails - get the SQL of a model save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to output the SQL UPDATES that would be generated by Rails, without actually running them or Saving the records.  I will be outputting the SQL updates to a file instead.

Is there a way to do this in Rails, without using string interpolation?

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
p = Post.where (something)

p.some_value = some_new_value

p.to_sql??? # how to generate the update statement
```

rather than:

```
"UPDATE TABLE SET field_1 = #{new_field} WHERE ID = " etc etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took from @R.F. Nelson and wrap it to a method. You could just calling `to_update_sql` with your model as the argument to get the SQL.

```
def to_update_sql(model)
  return '' if model.changes.empty?

  table = Arel::Table.new(model.class.table_name)
  update_manager = Arel::UpdateManager.new(model.class)
  update_manager.set(model.changes.map{|name, (_, val)| [table[name], val] })
                .where(table[:id].eq(model.id))
                .table(table)

  return update_manager.to_sql
end

post = Post.first
post.some_value = xxxx

to_update_sql(post)
# => UPDATE `posts` SET `some_value` = xxx WHERE `posts`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251546/convert-save-update-call-rails-to-sql):

You can achieve this goal with [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel):

```
# Arel::InsertManager
table = Arel::Table.new(:users)
insert_manager = Arel::InsertManager.new
insert_manager.into(table)
insert_manager.insert([ [table[:first_name], 'Eddie'] ])
sql_transaction = insert_manager.to_sql

File.open('file_name.txt', 'w') do |file| 
  file.write(sql)
end


# Arel::UpdateManager
table = Arel::Table.new(:users)
update_manager = Arel::UpdateManager.new
update_manager.set([[table[:first_name], "Vedder"]]).where(table[:id].eq(1)).table(table)
sql_transaction = update_manager.to_sql

File.open('file_name.txt', 'w') do |file| 
  file.write(sql)
end
```

[Here](https://github.com/rails/arel/tree/f50de54a6f0c59ab75526cfdb7896830130ffdf7/lib/arel) you can find all Arel managers, like **delete_manager.rb**, **select_manager.rb** and the others.

Good read: http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html

Comment: this is indeed interesting and thanks for answering, however  I still need to set all the variables in update_manager.set, so it may just be easier to go down the string iterpolation route...